# How to have the Rails Active Storage url link shortened it is too long

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I currently have a `Document` which `has_one_attached :file`

Currently when you use url_for(file)

it gives you something like

```
<a href="https://foobar/rails/active_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--d3d825ebe0cd321c3318539 babfe65e78ecc6db4/2020-2021%20PTC%20Continuation%20of%20Operation%20Plan.pdf?content_type=application%2Fpdf&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%222020-2021+PTC+Continuation+of+Operation+Plan.pdf%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%272020-2021%2520PTC%2520Continuation%2520of%2520Operation%2520Plan.pdf">Document File</a>
```

I'm currently using `service: Disk` as storage

Is there a way to have it shortened or to point the to something like:

```
<a href="https://foobar/documents/3/021+PTC+Continuation+of+Operation+Plan.pdf">
```

Answer (score 2):

I felt your pain, I finally found a solution.

try this: https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-activestorage-example

You just need to create the controller, model and add the 'uploads' resource in routes.rb